# When sql developer 4.0.2.15 is open I can not get .sql files to open

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When the sql developer application is open my sql scripts (.sql file extensions) will not open.  If I close sql developer and click on the .sql file the application opens.  I run many many scripts so I can open and close sql all day long. I did not have this issue in the previous version. Things I have tried: I have associated the files with the correct application using windows ***open with*** option.  I have selected: Tools: Preferences: File Types and made sure .sql had the ***open with sql developer box*** checked.  Here is the strange thing, after I make the preference selection for opening w/sql the preference selection doesn't stay put.  It becomes unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Any solution to this?  I'm having the same issue with version 19.2.1.247.  Pretty annoying.